# Accesing objects from a different layout

Tags: android, layout

I have two layouts called activity_portrait and activity_landscape. 
How can I access objects from activity which is not on the screen, for example when

```
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_portrait);

    //...
    // here need to access object from activity_landscape
    // for instance to set some buttonText
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? That's generally a horrible idea.

Comment: You should have a look at [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

Answer (score 0):

You need to inflate the layout first then you can access the items inside, but this is not a good idea.

```
View v = // inflate the layout

View yourViewItem = v.findViewItemById etc
```